# Windows programmatically change firewall profile

Tags: python, c++, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

for some reasons I need to change windows firewall profiles (private/public) programmatically for given adapter. It may be using command line, c++ or python. I was searching for any hint on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309(v=vs.85).aspx), but it seems to me that the only things I can change, are how firewall acts when some profile is running.

I imagine something like:

```
#include "Netfw.h"

int main()
{
    NET_FW_PROFILE* fwProfile = get_FirewallProfile("Local Area Connection");
    if(fwProfile.setProfile(NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIc))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Sorry if this pseudoexample is too dumb, I'm not much familiar with windows C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have a Windows machine at my disposal, but this may get you in the ballpark:

[How to use "netsh advfirewall" etc...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh-firewall-context-to-control-windows-firewall-behavior-in-windows-server-2008-and-in-windows-vista)

Example 5 seems to have some information about your question.